# Why are php files coming up 404 from IIS6 when they work OK the default site?

Tags: iis, php, http-status-code-404

Usually php on iis will thow 404 errors if the install doesn't go right.  However, danielcooper.dyndns.org/u.php works OK, but u.danielcooper.dyndns.org/u.php (different site in IIS, different folder) gives a 404 error.  However u.danielcooper.dyndns.org/test.php

Been using this instance on the default site for some time OK, but php does't seem to work (other than the test file) on a new site.

Am I going crazy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They all work for me.

```
danielcooper.dyndns.org/u.php      = 'test'
u.danielcooper.dyndns.org/u.php    = 'test'
u.danielcooper.dyndns.org/test.php = 'browserinfo..'
```

test.php includes phpinfo.. you might not want to publish that..

Comment: Hmmm, wouldn't work yesterday. http://u.danielcooper.dyndns.org/index.php still isn't working.

Comment: that worked for me, output ='No input file specified'

Which is a php error, not an IIS error or a 404.. so, its working!

Check your doc_root and cgi.force_redirect directives..

Comment: doc_root it was!